# If a complex function $f$ is Entire, and there exist $k,R > 0$, $n \in N$ such that $|f(z)| > k|z|^n$ for all $|z| > R$, then f is a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

As in the title, I must prove that:
If a complex function $f$ is Entire, and there exist $k,R > 0$, $n \in N$ such that $|f(z)| > k|z|^n$ for all $|z| > R$:
Then f is a polynomial.

We've already had a similar question with the inequality reversed, and found that it had to be a polynomial with degree less than n. I was able to show that if it was a polynomial, then it had to have degree less than n, but not that it had to be a polynomial in the first place.

Once again, I'm face with the same problem. I assume this time, the degree of the polynomial will have degree greater than or equal to n, but how do I show that such $f$ must be a polynomial?

It's not like I can go through every other possible function there is, can I? I can show it doesn't work for exponentials, for example, but I just can't think of how to show that this ONLY works for a polynomial...

Comment: Let $a_m$ be the zeros of $f(z)$ on $|z| \le R$. Then  $ \frac{\prod_{m=1}^M(z-a_m)}{f(z)}$ is entire and is bounded by $C(1+|z|^M)$ which means it is a polynomial by the Liouville theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a function can have only finitely many zeros. Let's say the zeros are $\zeta_1,\dotsc, \zeta_r$, with multiplicities $\mu_1,\dotsc, \mu_r$. Then consider

$$P(z) = \prod_{\rho = 1}^r (z - \zeta_{\rho})^{\mu_{\rho}}$$

and

$$g(z) = \frac{P(z)}{f(z)}.$$

After removing the removable singularities at the $\zeta_{\rho}$, $g$ is an entire function, and $g$ has no zeros (since the zeros of $f$ precisely cancel the zeros of $P$). And $g$ satisfies a growth condition

$$\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant k'\cdot \lvert z\rvert^{\deg P - n}$$

for $\lvert z\rvert > R'$. So $g$ is a polynomial, and since it has no zeros, it is constant. That means $f(z) = c\cdot P(z)$.

Comment: Could you explain to me, or point me towards the theorem that states why such a function can only have finitely many zeroes? Thanks

Comment: The condition $\lvert f(z)\rvert > k\lvert z\rvert^n$ for $\lvert z\rvert > R$ shows that all zeros of $f$ lie in the disk $\overline{D_R(0)} = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\}$. By the identity theorem, the zeros of $f$ are isolated (since $f$ isn't identically $0$), and since the disk is compact, it can contain only finitely many zeros. And every zero has a finite multiplicity.